# call function on hit enter in input search field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

**My Html code:**

```
<div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Text" ng-model="csrModel.accountNumber" />
                <span class="input-group-addon" ng-click="csrModel.search(csrModel.accountNumber)">
                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </span>
            </div>
```

I have input box which I am using as a search field. On click of span i am calling `ng-click` function.
Same think I want when user will enter after some text in input field i need to call `ng-click` function.

[image]

Please suggest me what to use.
I tried to use some form element but it screw my design. I don't wanna change look and design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Text" 
ng-model="csrModel.accountNumber" 
ng-keyup="callOnEnter($event,csrModel.accountNumber)"/>
```

and in JS

```
$scope.callOnEnter = function($event, accountNumber) {
 if ($event.keyCode === 13) {
   $scope.csrModel.search(accountNumber);
 }
}
```

It is more angular way

Answer (score 1):

Bind an ng-keypress or ng-keyup event on the input and in the handler, check for the key-code and accordingly proceed.

```
<div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Text" ng-model="csrModel.accountNumber" ng-keyup="submitOnEnter()"/>
            <span class="input-group-addon" ng-click="csrModel.search(csrModel.accountNumber)">
                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </span>
        </div>


$scope.submitOnEnter = function () {
/*--------*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
<div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-keyup="keyPress($event.keyCode)" placeholder="Enter Text" ng-model="csrModel.accountNumber" />
                <span class="input-group-addon"  ng-click="csrModel.search(csrModel.accountNumber)">
                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </span>
            </div>
```

Controller::

```
$scope.keyPress = function(keyCode){
   console.log(keyCode); 
  if(keyCode == 13)
    {
      // Call the func if user enters 13 i.e for Enter
    } 



}
```